# General solution to $ \frac{dx}{dt} = x^a(1-x)^b$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

My question is about the general solution for the following differential equation: 
$$ \frac{dx}{dt}  = x^a(1-x)^b,\quad a,b\gt 0~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)~. $$

Obviously, if $a=b=1$ then (1) reduces to 
$$ \frac{dx}{dt}  = x(1-x) $$ which has as solution $$ x(t) = \frac{1}{1 + A e^{-t}}\,,$$ for some constant, $A$. In fact, for $a,b$ positive integers, a solution can be obtained by using method of separation of variables and partial fractions. I want to be able to find a solution that considers all cases and which would obviously include the special cases when $a$ and $b$ are positive integers.

Comment: you can still separate the variables, the only question is how to integrate $$\int \frac{dx}{x^a(1-x)^b}$$

Comment: Looks like an incomplete beta function. At least for some a and b.

Comment: this equation leads to a hypergeometric function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your differential equation is separable:

$$\int \frac{1}{x^a(1-x)^b}~dx=\int dt \tag{1}$$

The left hand side cannot be integrated in terms of elementary functions.

> However, one can directly apply the definition of the [incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function):
>
> $$\operatorname*{B}(x;\,m,n) = \int_0^x t^{m-1}\,(1-t)^{n-1}\,dt \tag{2}$$

If we put $(1)$ into a similar form:

$$\int x^{-a}(1-x)^{-b}~dx=t+c_1 \tag{3}$$

Hence, after applying $(2)$, the integral on the left hand side is evaluated as:
$$\int x^{-a}(1-x)^{-b}~dx=\operatorname*{B}(x,1-a,1-b)+c_2$$
Therefore, the general solution in implicit form is simply:
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\operatorname*{B}(x;1-a,1-b)=t+C}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would the solution change if initial condition, say $x(t_0) = x_0$ is given? I'm a little bit confused with the application of the Beta function. The right hand side would evaluate to $t-t_0$, but what about the left hand side?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, all you need to do is substitute $t=t_0$ and $x=x_0$ to evaluate $C$.
$$\operatorname*{B}(x_0;1-a,1-b)=t_0+C$$
$$C=\operatorname*{B}(x_0;1-a,1-b)-t_0$$
Hence, the general solution in implicit form is:
$$\operatorname*{B}(x;1-a,1-b)=t+\operatorname*{B}(x_0;1-a,1-b)-t_0$$

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. Thanks. Another question. How would the solution like if for example $a$ is fixed but $b\to \infty$. What about both $a\to \infty,b\to \infty$?

Answer (score 1):

Well, we have:

$$\text{x}'\left(t\right)=\text{x}\left(t\right)^\text{a}\cdot\left(1-\text{x}\left(t\right)\right)^\text{b}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\int\frac{\text{x}'\left(t\right)}{\text{x}\left(t\right)^\text{a}\cdot\left(1-\text{x}\left(t\right)\right)^\text{b}}\space\text{d}x=\int1\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

For the integrals:

- $$\int1\space\text{d}x=x+\text{C}_1\tag2$$
- Substitute $\text{u}=\text{x}\left(t\right)$:
  $$\int\frac{\text{x}'\left(t\right)}{\text{x}\left(t\right)^\text{a}\cdot\left(1-\text{x}\left(t\right)\right)^\text{b}}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{1}{\text{u}^\text{a}\cdot\left(1-\text{u}\right)^\text{b}}\space\text{d}\text{u}\tag3$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer.